# How do I make a custom taxomony appear like tags?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I have a custom taxonomy which I want to behave in the same way that tags do on the post edit screen, instead of how categories appear. I have tried passing in the `'show_tagcloud' => true` attribute, but it is still behaving like categories.

Comment: What does "it behaving like categories not tags" mean?

Comment: Means not as wordpress default tags

Comment: Set `hierarchical` to false when you register your taxonomy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass this argument in register_taxonomy(),

```
'hierarchical' => false,
'_builtin'=>true,
```

or use following links

[How to Add Tags to Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62260/how-to-add-tags-to-custom-post-type)

[Adding post tags to custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29932/adding-post-tags-to-custom-post-types)

Comment: I'm not so sure why you would set `_builtin` to `true` - are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Also, those two links are unreleated to this question - they specify adding the built-in tags taxonomy to a custom post type, where as this question refers to making a custom taxonomy behave similar to the built-in tags taxonomy.